# vue data binding to an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

pls am trying to send an array to another component like this

```
<paystack
            :amount="parseFloat(props.item.amount)"
            :email="$store.state.email"
            :reference="reference"
            :callback="callback"
            :close="close"
            pin=""
            :returnVal=[props.item.amount, props.item.biddedBy]
            ref="pay"
            v-if="!givenTo"
            transType="payment"
            :embed="false"
            :valid="true"
              >
              <i>Award</i>
          </paystack>
```

but it didnt work, pls how can i do it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the quotation marks

```
:returnVal="[props.item.amount, props.item.biddedBy]"
```